# autonavi / amap xyz tile layer appears shifted in OpenLayers (Chinese Web Mercator with GCJ-02 datum)

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, datum, xyz-tiles, china

I am trying to add an xyz source tile layer to OpenLayers v8.1.

The source URI for the tiles is the Chinese autonavi / amap provider.

`http://webrd0{1-4}.is.autonavi.com/appmaptile?lang=zh_cn&size=1&scale=1&style=8&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}`

When overlaid to the default OSM layer the amap tile layer appears shifted.

[image]

The shift of roughly 500m east, and 200m south seems to indicate that the autonavi tiles use a webmercator projection with a pseudo-datum like [GCJ-02](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrictions_on_geographic_data_in_China#GCJ-02)

Also referenced in this PROJ [issue](https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/issues/982).

Does anybody know how to apply the datum shift to a web mercator projection for this XYZ/Tile layer?

I've created a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/dbauszus-glx/pen/LYqZaNE).

```js
const amap_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  opacity: 0.5,
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url:
      "http://webrd0{1-4}.is.autonavi.com/appmaptile?lang=zh_cn&size=1&scale=1&style=8&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}"
  })
});

new ol.Map({
  target: "OL",
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    amap_layer
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([120.3, 30.3]),
    zoom: 13
  }),
  controls: [
    new ol.control.Zoom(),
    new ol.control.ScaleLine({
      minWidth: 64,
      units: "metric"
    })
  ]
});
```

Comment: You need to specify the projection in the source https://codepen.io/mike-000/pen/PoVzgEX

Comment: If I set the Baidu project the map is completely misaligned. I don't really know what the AMAP projection. It's like web mercator with a GCJ-02 datum. @Mike if I open your codepen fork the amap is completely misaligned not just slightly shifted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Baidu layer will align with OSM (but not using https) by changing `var y = tileCoord[2];` to `var y = -tileCoord[2] - 1;` (see https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/10374)

For the amap layer you need a mercator projection based on the GCJ02 transforms - I found a transform between GCJ02 lon/lat values and EPSG:4326 and EPSG:3857.  The normal EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 transforms can then be applied to create a GCJ02 mercator projection from the GCJ02 lon/lat projection:

```
import {GCJ02} from "https://esm.sh/ol-proj-ch";

const gcj02Mercator = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: "gcj02",
  extent: ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857').getExtent(),
  units: "m"
});

const ll2merc = ol.proj.getTransform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
const merc2ll = ol.proj.getTransform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');

ol.proj.addProjection(gcj02Mercator);

ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms(
  "EPSG:4326",
  gcj02Mercator,
  (x) => ll2merc(GCJ02.fromEPSG4326(x)),
  (x) => GCJ02.toEPSG4326(merc2ll(x))
);

ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms(
  "EPSG:3857",
  gcj02Mercator,
  (x) => ll2merc(GCJ02.fromEPSG3857(x)),
  (x) => GCJ02.toEPSG3857(merc2ll(x))
);

const amap_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  opacity: 0.5,
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    projection: 'gcj02',
    url:
      "http://webrd0{1-4}.is.autonavi.com/appmaptile?lang=zh_cn&size=1&scale=1&style=8&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}"
  })
});
```

Working demo with layer switcher added http://mikenunn.x10host.com/demo/baidu.html

Comment: Thanks so much for doing this. This works perfectly. I have updated my codepen to reflect the changes.